# SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer) in Glide 4.11.0 while showing image from firebase strorage

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-glide, sslhandshakeexception, sslexception

While showing an image from downloadurl  from firebase storage, i get this error from glide library.

> Load failed for
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/java-project-21.appspot.com/o/yFERY8j8snZesnVfrn74TNekTUR2.jpg?alt=media&token=ba062708-83f6-4d0e-b3fd-d3a9a69ed24d
>   with size [140x140]
>       class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>       There was 1 cause:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
>       There was 1 cause:
>
> > ```
> > javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer)
> >  call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
> >     Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
> > There was 1 cause:
> > javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer)
> >  call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
> >       Cause (1 of 1): class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer 2020-03-29 12:47:18.165
> > ```
> >
> > 13829-13829/com.example.javaproject21 I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
> >         javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
> >             at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
> >     Method)
> >             at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@200616026@20.06.16
> >     (100306-296104215):6)
> >             at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@200616026@20.06.16
> >     (100306-296104215):14)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:1483)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1427)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1371)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:488)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
> >             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:100)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
> >             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

my code for showing image -

```
Glide.with(view).setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().timeout(30*1000)).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.classroom).into(imageView);
```

my glide version is **'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'**
my firebase settings and dependencies are latest and correct. Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: I have the Same Question, anyone not yet answer !

Comment: @NoorHossain I contacted with firebase support. Their reply is that this is only happening in Bangladesh. Our so much brilliant Govt. has blocked firebase storage API. I used a mobile VPN in was working fine. They said that they are trying to contact the Govt. Till then, don't delete your code or change it. It's not our fault.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply!